# Not able to click the hidden calendar box

Tags: selenium-webdriver

The calendar box I am working on is having today's date as default, it doesn't have any specific id to click on the calendar box, therefore, I have built the below x-path, it highlights the box when I tried it in the console area of chrome browser, however, it is not clicking the calendar box to select the dates when I run the code,

Here is my source code,

I guess this is hidden,

```
<div class="hidden-xs hidden-sm item-container--dropdown">
 <span ng-bind="$ctrl.selectedDate | date : $ctrl.dateStyleFormat" class="ng-binding">2 May 2018</span>
 <span class="dropdown--icon icon icon--calendar"></span>
</div>
<input type="text" ng-focus="$ctrl.openDatePickerPopup()" readonly="" uib-datepicker-popup="dd MMM yyyy" ng-model="$ctrl.selectedDate" is-open="$ctrl.popup.opened" datepicker-options="$ctrl.dateOptions" ng-required="true" close-text="Close" alt-input-formats="$ctrl.altInputFormats" show-button-bar="false" class="ng-pristine ng-valid ng-isolate-scope ng-not-empty ng-valid-required ng-valid-date ng-touched" required="required" style="">
```

Here is my code,

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='uib-datepicker-wrapper ']/span/input[@ng-model='$ctrl.selectedDate']")).click();
```

Comment: To show calendar box locate an input that triggers the calendar to show. And click on it. After that you can work with calendar box itself

Comment: as it is `input` tag, did you try entering date using `sendKeys` instead of clicking?

Comment: MoveToElement("To calendar object") works fine but unable to click or do any action on the date calendar.@NaveenKumarRB